# pattern matching within two bash arrays

Tags: arrays, linux, string, bash, pattern-matching

I found quite a few posts on this but couldn't put together the pieces to solve my issue. So say I have two arrays:

```
array1=( adir bdir anicedir )
array2=( adir anice )
```

I would like to have a third array like so

```
array3=( adir anicedir )
```

More specifically if the first 5 characters of the i-th element in `array2` match the first 5 characters of any element in `array1` then substitute `array2[i]` with `array1[i]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing particularly short, because `bash` isn't a data-processing language. You need to use a loop.

```
array1=( adir bdir anicedir )
array2=( adir anice )
array3=()

for val2 in "${array2[@]}"; do
    for val1 in "${array1[@]}"; do
        if [[ ${val1:0:5} == "${val2:0:5}" ]]; then
            array3+=("$val1")
            break
        fi
    done
done
```

Quoting the right-hand side of `==` ensures that literal string comparison, not pattern matching, is performed.

Comment: OK, though it still gives me no output. Does `echo ${array3[@]}` give to you the correct output?

Comment: Now I get `echo ${array3[@]} adir anice` but it should be `echo ${array3[@]} adir anicedir`. Anyway it already helps, I will try to figure it out. Thanks

Comment: Ah, misread the desired output. Fixed, and in a much simpler manner. Just use substring expansion `${<var>:<star>t:<length>}` to compare the 5-character prefix of each array element to each other.

Comment: Yeah I think that now it's spot on. Thanks